# JavaScript - assignment - array of arrays

Tags: php, javascript, asp.net, .net, html

```
var a = new Array();
var b = new Array();
var c = [a,b];

var str = 'hello,world,nice,day';
for(var i = 0; i < c.length; i++){
  c[i] = str.split(',');
}
```

After execution i'd like to have:

```
c = [a, b];
a = ['hello', 'world', 'nice', 'day'];
b = ['hello', 'world', 'nice', 'day'];
```

but really i have:

```
c = [['hello', 'world', 'nice', 'day'], ['hello', 'world', 'nice', 'day']];
a = [];
b = [];
```

could i fix it?

**upd:**
Decision by Raynos is really nice. Thx.

Comment: I'm surprised you get a=null,b=null, shouldn't a and b be empty arrays?

Comment: When i wrote a=null, b=null it's mean they are empty arrays. Sorry for my mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for(var i = 0; i < c.length; i++){
  c[i].push.apply(c[i], str.split(','));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `split` function creates a new array, that is stored in `c`. You have to loop through the array returned by `split` and do `c[i].push()` on that value.

Or just set `a` and `b` directly to the result of `split`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you wrote `c[i] = str.split(',');` - you should write `c[i] = str.split(',')[i];`
And actually - why go over it with `for`?

Edit - Sorry, thought the assignment was to c[0], c[1]....

Comment: str.split(',')[i]. Are u sure about answer?

Comment: that doesn't do what he wants at all

Comment: I'm sure about the syntax - but I've edited my answer, didn't noticed the first part of `c = [a,b]`